# Android Media Player File Location

Tags: android, mp3, media

I'm trying to run a mp3 file using android media player. I'm using this code below

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, "mmt/sdcard/mp3/file.mp3"); 
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But Ecliplse showing error & it says I can't use string as argument of create method. How can I run the file using this file location?

Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `setDataSource` to set the source of your media files. For files on the sdcard, the `setDataSource(String ds)` works best.

Also, note that your url should probably be **mnt** instead of **mmt**, and you need a forwardslash at the beginning, making your full url look like this: `/mnt/sdcard/mp3/file.mp3`